# Create dataframe where no. of rows based on splitting array into 'n' batches in Spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

**Data**

```
{"GPS":[{"TimeStamp": 1605449171.259277, "Longitude": -76.463684, "Latitude": 40.787052}, 
{"TimeStamp": 1605449175.743052, "Longitude": -76.464046, "Latitude": 40.787038}, 
{"TimeStamp": 1605449180.932659, "Longitude": -77.764465, "Latitude": 41.987022}, 
{"TimeStamp": 1605449181.945252, "Longitude": -78.864324, "Latitude": 42.234242}, 
{"TimeStamp": 1605449182.532659, "Longitude": -79.964465, "Latitude": 43.887022}, 
{"TimeStamp": 1605449183.743052, "Longitude": -80.804046, "Latitude": 44.187038}, 
{"TimeStamp": 1605449184.332659, "Longitude": -81.164465, "Latitude": 45.687022}, 
{"TimeStamp": 1605449185.143052, "Longitude": -82.264046, "Latitude": 46.987038}, 
{"TimeStamp": 1605449186.932659, "Longitude": -83.364465, "Latitude": 47.387022}, 
{"TimeStamp": 1605449187.843052, "Longitude": -84.964046, "Latitude": 48.287038}, 
{"TimeStamp": 1605449188.932659, "Longitude": -85.464465, "Latitude": 49.587022}, 
{"TimeStamp": 1605449189.288478, "Longitude": -87.164977, "Latitude": 50.287054}]}
```

**Schema**

```
val gpsSchema: StructType = 
  StructType(Array(
    StructField("GPS", ArrayType(
      StructType(Array(
          StructField("TimeStamp",DoubleType,true),
          StructField("Longitude", DoubleType, true),
          StructField("Latitude",DoubleType,true)
          )),true),true)))
```

Given the `GPS` array above which has 12 elements. How do we split it into batches of 5 so that the resulting dataframe can have a total of three rows with the first 5 elements in the first row, the next 5 elements in the second row, and the remaining 2 elements in the third row?

One way is to explode the array, index each row with the remainder of `(montically_increasing_id + 1) / 5`. Here the rows 1 to 5 will have remainder 0, rows 6 to 10 will have remainder of 1 and rows 11 and 12 will have remainder of 2. We can then group by remainder and then do a collect_list.

Since the array size may be in the thousands and could burden the driver node of the spark cluster (spark 2.45 and scala 2.11) is there a way to do this without `explode` and `collect_list` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `union`:

1. Get the size `gpsSize` of the column `GPS`
2. Map in range 1 to `gpsSize` by step of 5 and in each iteration [`slice`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#slice) the array column
3. Reduce the list of resulting data frames by union

```scala
// get max size
val gpsSize = df.select(max(size($"GPS"))).first.getInt(0)

val df1 = (1 to gpsSize by 5)
  .map(i => df.select(slice($"GPS", i, 5).alias("GPS")))
  .reduce(_ unionAll _)
  .filter(size($"GPS")> 0)

df1.show(false)

//+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|GPS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
//+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|[[40.787052, -76.463684, 1.605449171259277E9], [40.787038, -76.464046, 1.605449175743052E9], [41.987022, -77.764465, 1.605449180932659E9], [42.234242, -78.864324, 1.605449181945252E9], [43.887022, -79.964465, 1.605449182532659E9]]|
//|[[44.187038, -80.804046, 1.605449183743052E9], [45.687022, -81.164465, 1.605449184332659E9], [46.987038, -82.264046, 1.605449185143052E9], [47.387022, -83.364465, 1.605449186932659E9], [48.287038, -84.964046, 1.605449187843052E9]]|
//|[[49.587022, -85.464465, 1.605449188932659E9], [50.287054, -87.164977, 1.605449189288478E9]]                                                                                                                                          |
//+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to deal with variable array size in the json. Essentially it's generating @blackbishop's slice dynamically from the size of the array.

```
val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "seq",
    expr("explode(sequence(1, size(GPS), 5))")
).withColumn(
    "GPS",
    expr("slice(GPS, seq, 5)")
).drop("seq")

df2.show(false)
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|GPS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[40.787052, -76.463684, 1.605449171259277E9], [40.787038, -76.464046, 1.605449175743052E9], [41.987022, -77.764465, 1.605449180932659E9], [42.234242, -78.864324, 1.605449181945252E9], [43.887022, -79.964465, 1.605449182532659E9]]|
|[[44.187038, -80.804046, 1.605449183743052E9], [45.687022, -81.164465, 1.605449184332659E9], [46.987038, -82.264046, 1.605449185143052E9], [47.387022, -83.364465, 1.605449186932659E9], [48.287038, -84.964046, 1.605449187843052E9]]|
|[[49.587022, -85.464465, 1.605449188932659E9], [50.287054, -87.164977, 1.605449189288478E9]]                                                                                                                                          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```